Understanding the Inequality Involving the Probability of Algorithmic Error and Expectation
I am trying to understand the following two inequalities involving a random symmetric matrix $\Theta$ and an algorithm $B$:
$ P(B, \Theta) \geq 0.5 \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{I}_{K,L \text{ is not queried}} \mid (K, L)\right] $
where:
$\Theta = \Theta(C, V_1, \ldots, V_{m-1}, K, L)$ is defined by:

$C$: A Bernoulli random variable with parameter 0.5.

$V_1, \ldots, V_{m-1}$: Independent uniform random variables on $[0, 1]$.

$K, L$: Different indices uniformly distributed over all $(m-1)(m-2)$ pairs.


$P(B, \Theta) = P(U(B) \neq U(\Theta))$ is the probability that the tree output by the algorithm $B$ is not equal to the tree induced by $\Theta$.
$\mathbb{I}_{K,L \text{ is not queried}}$ is an indicator variable that is 1 if the entry $\Theta_{K,L}$ is not queried by the algorithm $B$.
$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_{K,L \text{ is not queried}} \mid (K, L)]$ is the expectation of this indicator variable conditioned on the indices $K$ and $L$.
The algorithm $B$ is unable to distinguish between $\Theta(0, V_1, \ldots, V_{m-1}, K, L)$ and $\Theta(1, V_1, \ldots, V_{m-1}, K, L)$ before querying the entry $\Theta_{K,L}$.
I am trying to understand:
The intuition behind why the expectation $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_{K,L \text{ is not queried}} \mid (K, L)]$ appears in the inequality.
How this expectation relates to the probability of error $P(B, \Theta)$.
